# Could a PIC18 running two functions simultaneously?

Tags: pic, c, microprocessor, mplabx, xc8

I am building a robotic car with stepper motors (for wheels) and infrared sensors(avoiding obstracles) using PIC18F4550 microcontroller.

So, I have created a function to drive the stepper motor steps by steps and it works fine.

```
void move_forward(int steps)
{
   // Code to drive stepper motor step by step
}
```

Then I created a function to read the infrared sensor output.

Let's say

```
int read_distance_from_sensor(void)
{
 // Code to read the analog input and return distance 
}
```

It works fine too. But my problem is how do I run the `read_distance_from_sensor()` function while the stepper motor function is running?

From what I understand, everything gets executed one after another in the PIC18  and it is not possible to execute 2 tasks at the same time simultaneously.

If I do the following:

```
void main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        move_forward(20);
        if (read_distance_from_sensor<10)
        {
            // Stop 
        }
    }
}
```

It will move forward first then it stop to get the distance measurement.

I want it to return the distance measurement while it is on the move.

Do I have to call the `read_distance_from_sensor()` function inside the `move_forward()` function everytime i move a step for motor?

Is there a clever way to accomplish this?

Comment: You'd need threads, but this may be overkill. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624237/multithreading-using-c-on-pic18

Comment: Rather than moving forward 20, why not move forward 1, read sensor, move forward 1 ...

Comment: It depends on the method you use to control your motors. Do you have to wait until the motor has completed turning to return from the function?

Comment: There are many options, including the use of threads (if you use some form of RTOS), timer-based interrupts, interleaving your code, using state machines... which one is the best option for you depends a lot on what you do in those functions, what other tasks you may have to perform at the same time, the time-sensitivity of each operation, the relationship between those operations, and more... We lack details.

Comment: And you should read your sensor at a fixed timebase (e.g. 10ms), not just running full speed in your loop.

Comment: Ignore everyone rambling about threads and RTOS... Multi-tasking on low-end microcontrollers is achieved by telling different hardware to do different things at the same time. If you for example drive a motor with PWM at the same time as you pick up readings with an ADC, then both the PWM and the ADC hardware peripherals can do their work without involving the CPU at all. The CPU just has to step in on regular basis and synchronize the PWM based on the ADC. So the answer to your question depends on _how_ do you drive the stepper motor and _how_ do you collect data from _what kind_ of sensor?

Comment: Use the peripherals, use interrupts as required, and don't write blocking code.